# Mongodb Atlas - pipeline length greater than 50 not supported

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

When i use mongoose for mongodb with an atlas mongo sever , it gives the error that mongo pipeline length greater than 50 not supported.
I have searched the whole web for this.cant find  a solution.
Is there a work around on this?

Comment: Any update? Can someone show me a link to doc where says that the limit is 50? i see mongo states that the limit is 1000 and later they talk about memory usage.
Is this a mongoose problem or mongo?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you have used too many pipelines in one aggregation.
If you want to use more than 50 pipeline stages, you can use $facet.
The following workflow may be of help:

1. Separate your pipelines into several chunks (pipeline stages in each chunk must not exceed 50).
2. After running the facet, you can use $unwind to separate the result into separate documents like normal (you may need to restructure the data to restore the former format using $project).
3. You can run another facet after that if you want.

In this case, if you plan to run 150 stages in one aggregation, you separate them into 4-5 chunks, make sure that each chunk must use the same scope to avoid causing "missing" or "undefined variable" case, you can $use unwind to restore the document format to run the next chunk, too.

Make sure that each output document must not exceed 16MB, that's why I recommend using $unwind after $facet (it can excced 16MB during the stages). The reason is that the $facet will output everything into 1 document with an array of documents inside (if you want to show all documents), so $unwind will separate those "inner" documents into separate documents.

One note on this is that you can try limit the field name to prevent BufBuilder to exceed maximum size, which is 64MB. Try using $project instead of $addFields as it will increase the buffer between each stage.
Another one is that you should not use pipeline stages that exceed 100MB of RAM if you are using MongoDB Atlas < M10.

It may be better if you provide a pseudo-code for the problem you are having but I think this would fix it.